# Ion-content with ion-list only shown in small area of my component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my page I use two components next to each other like this:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col  size=4>
    <list-component></list-component>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size=8>
    <news-component></news-component>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

In the list-component I want to use a scrollable list like this from the ionic docs:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Pokémon Yellow</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Mega Man X</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

When I use it like this, the whole page scrolls including the news-component.
So I checked google and found that I need to use the list inside an ion-content block. So I tried it like this:

```
<ion-content
        [scrollEvents]="true"
        (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()"
        (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
        (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Pokémon Yellow</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Mega Man X</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

But now I have the problem that the list is shown only in a small window and not in the whole component.

[image: List in small window]

When I add a height like example below it works, but then it is not dynamic. I want to give it like 90% of the height of the component. But my magic is not that strong to do so...

```
<ion-content style="height: 66vh">
```

[image: List with static height]

What do I have forgotten to make it work?

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v12.4.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : macOS Catalina

Comment: Normally when I see something like this its because an error has occurred and the dynamic sizing scripting hasn't run. Have you checked the error console in your browser?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I just wanted to check the browser console log. But now it works as expected. I have no clue why. Maybe I alway wait three weeks if a problem occurs... 

Answer (score 0):

Okay, After I had a look at it again three weeks later, it works as expected. I don't know why, but this can be closed.

Comment: You probably had something cached. It's recommended to work with the browser dev tools open so that the cache is disabled (and you see any errors straight away).

Comment: I always have these tools open. ‍♂️